# What's different between run code - run java vscode? And error Could not find or load main class? And package?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package, src

I am coding java on vscode. I have source folder:

```
  >...
  >lib
  >>src
    exam1.java
    exam1.class
    >>Month10
      app1.class
      app1.java
```

With:

```
exam1.java 
public class exam1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    } 
}

app1.java
package Month10;

public class app1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I want to ask about why I need to use package Month10 in here. And another, exam1.java run well(both run code and run java), but in app1.java, I only can "run java", can't "run code" (Ctrl+Alt+N in vs code), it exists error Could not find or load main class app1, I think because the command package? (I saved file before running), can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)** extension sometimes has problems running code under multiple levels of folders. For a better coding experience, please use the [official extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to run the code.

*Tips:*

`Run Code` is provided by **Code Runner**

`Run Java` and `Debug Java` are provided by the official extension

[image]

*You can ask questions about the **Code Runne** [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues).*

Answer (score 0):

reload VS Code window or F1 ->Clean the java language server workspace. try this could help